# Dirac paper quoted at Wikipedia

Tags: quantum-mechanics, specific-reference

From Wikipedia's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle:

> In 1936 Dirac offered a precise definition and derivation of the time-energy uncertainty relation in a relativistic quantum theory of "events".

The citation to the paper is missing. Can anyone provide the title of this paper and where can I find it? Thanks.

Comment: Dirac's famous book "The Principles of Quantum Mechanics" has a chapter on the uncertainty relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference is to the "many-time" formalism which was influential for Feynman Schwinger and especially Tomonaga. It gives the evolution in an interaction picture. I never read the reference, I heard Tomonaga mention it. It's from 1932, not 1936, and Tomonaga writes a follow up in 1946. See the first page of this reference: [Link](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01807524).

Answer (score 4):

It could be this one, although the paragraph author *should* have provided the reference:

- P. A. M. Dirac, "[Relativistic Wave Equations](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1936RSPSA.155..447D)". In *Proc. R. Soc. London*, series A. *Math. Phys. Sc.* **155** (886) 447-459.

This was obtained from the [SAO/NASA Astrophysical Data System](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-basic_connect). Please note that for that year (1936) this "search engine" also provides [another paper by Dirac](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1936Natur.137..298D) but at a glance it doesn't seem to be the one you're after.

Comment: http://www.springerlink.com/content/nwq557633112kxk2/ says the year is 1932, and gives the other references.

Comment: Also, I wrote that paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

The discussion in Dirac's book only pertains to the position-momentum uncertainty relation; the question is about the time-energy uncertainty relation which is claimed by many (e.g. Bohm & Aharanov http://148.216.10.84/archivoshistoricosMQ/ModernaHist/Aharonov%20a.pdf) to be fundamentally different.

The reference that I have just given is known to the becko because it's from the Wikipedia article that he cites. Others might like to read it (I mean try to read it).